# Magnetometer in space

Tags: orbital-mechanics, magnetic-field, flight-computer

See, i recently buy a magnetometer to experiment with arduino, i want start building a litle fly computer for a cubesat (this cubesat have an ion engine, so, have thrust).
I start reading the Azimuth of the magnetomenter and all was ok, my question is: What is the use of a magnetometer in fly computers? is for detect the North as a compass or just to detect the X-axis move?, and: a Magnetometer work equal in the space as in the earth? i think no, bcs uses the Magnetic field of the earth to detect, right?
I buy an accelerometer + gyroscope too so i know how detect the rest of the axis of move and velocity. Thats why i just find that use on the Magnetomenter.

Thanks for any help or document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert in this but I think this is right as far as it goes. Your question is about the use of a magnetometer in space with Arduino style sensors and algorithms, so I can provide some links which will be helpful.

---

On earth in a local area like a room up to kilometer-sized flying radius, people *try to use* magnetometers to help establish a baseline for their algorithm that uses gyro signals to determine direction.

A stream of signals from a gyro might tell you that you've turned about 20 degrees ccw in the last 5 seconds, but "20 degrees from what?" is the question. The answer is "From wherever you were pointing five seconds ago." As long as you are flying gyros-only you have to keep adding every change to the list of previous changes to see where you are pointing now.

Gyros always have errors and offsets, they can think they are spinning when they aren't, can be nonlinear and can mix rotations in different axes together incorrectly or misinterpret accelerations as rotations, *especially* the ones we use with hobby projects.

**So people turn to our friend the Earth and its stable magnetic field** because it tends to point in a fixed direction locally.

When the accumulated gyro errors start deviating too much from the compass direction too much, the attitude is combined with, or reset to the compass information as best as it can be guessed. Every algorithm is different.

The problem is that the compass can not tell you anything about rotation around the magnetic field direction, which at mid-latitudes points diagonally up out of the ground.

- [How do simple compass needles remain level instead of see-sawing with magnetic dip? Are they flat even near the poles?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/21360/12619)

**Luckily our friend the Earth gives us a second stable field as well,** ***gravity!***<sup>1</sup> We can use the axis of the local magnetic field and the axis of the local gravitational field to build a non-rotational fixed frame.

Problems:

Any ferromagnetic materials like iron in the ground or rocks or buildings (e.g. rebar in reinforced concrete) will distort the local magnetic field.

- [Is there a “submerged object” in Australia that causes a magnetic deviation of 20 degrees?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/15222/6031)

And the Earth plays games with its magnetic field as well!

- [Does a geomagnetic storm visibly deflect a compass?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19303/6031)
- [What is the nature of the “unexpected geomagnetic pulse that took place beneath South America in 2016”?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/15948/6031)

as do other planets!

- [How could the solar wind cause strange magnetic pulses on Mars at midnight?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19325/6031)
- [Mars' strange magnetic pulses at midnight; besides the solar wind what are other possible causes?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19324/6031)
- [Now Mars is pulsing 3 times per night in the UV, can anyone explain these waves in simple terms? Do these waves happen on Earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/20043/6031)

Low cost hobby or cellphone compass modules are suboptimal:

- [Why do compass chips in cellphones require frequent calibration?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/249072/102305)
- [How is the degaussing feature in the HMC5883L 3-Axis Digital Compass chip correctly used?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/249086/102305)

As are the accelerometers:

- [MPU6050 accel/gyro noise that behaves strangely - what might be doing this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/333174/102305)
- [Yaw from accelerometer? No! So what do these equations actually mean?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/14305/17872) lesson learned: don't believe everything you read in people's blogs; [trust, but verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust,_but_verify) (misnomer alert!)

More background:

The implementation of gyros (sometimes together with accelerometers) for absolute pointing is sometimes called a gyrocompass.

- [How does Curiosity know how to point and move it's high gain antenna in real time?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26679/12102)
- [What is a gyrocompass and how might one be used by a planetary rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26696/12102)
- [Are there types of compass other than the regular magnetic one and the gyrocompass?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/15225/12619)

Great flying often involves the incorporation of several different streams of data from very different sources. Motion detection and patter recognition from vision systems are used by insects and birds and some drone flying algorithms, radar (radio or acoustic pings) doppler (radio, audio), laser scanners for field mapping can and have all also be explored at the hobby level as well.

- e.g. [What wavelengths are most commonly used in laser-scanners and LIDAR systems?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/18014/17872)

---

<sup>1</sup>note added in proof; "down" from gravity is not available to those in orbit!

Answer (score 2):

The magnetometer in cubesats is used in attitude determination, in general for measure of local earth magnetic field vector. To implement the most basic attitude determination algorithm (TRIAD) you will need 4 vectors, related to two physical quantities (usually the magnetic field and sun position), two of them observed with sensors and the other two with reference from the orbit propagation<sup>1</sup>.

The reference sun vector is easily archived by estimate the sun position of a given orbit. The magnetic vector reference you need the orbit information and an Earth magnetic model (like world magnetic model-WMM, or
International Geomagnetic Reference Field - IGRF).

---

<sup>1</sup>For attitude determination, essentially, you need to find a rotation operator (a cosine matrix for example) to apply on the coordinate system fixed on the satellite body to reach on a given inertial reference system (e.g.ECI - Earth-Centered Inertia). With a vector described (components) on both coordinate system ("observe vector" in the satellite body and a "reference vector" in the referential system) you can determine the rotation operator but with some ambiguities. You can work with two vectors described in the two systems (two obs and two ref) you can resolve these ambiguities

Comment: Nice answer! Can you add a little bit more explaining why four vectors related to two quantities are needed? Maybe it's *two vectors* representing four quantities (vector components or angles)?

Comment: Thks ^^ For attitude determination, essentially, you need to find a rotation operator (a cosine matrix for example) to apply on the coordinate system fixed on the satellite body to reach on a given inertial reference system (e.g.ECI - Earth-Centered Inertia). With a vector described (components) on both coordinate system ("observe vector" in the satellite body and a "reference vector" in the referential system) you can determine the rotation operator but with some ambiguities. You can work with two vectors described in the two systems (two obs and two ref) you can resolve these ambiguities.

Comment: Okay thanks. I pasted that back into your answer as a footnote, please feel free to edit further if you like. The idea is that comments are considered temporary, so anything that's important we should try to move back into the post itself. Welcome to Stack Exchange!