# What is VBB recentering (InSight lander's Very Broad Band seismic pendulums)?

Tags: mars, insight, measurement, scientific-data, seismology

From the Planetary Society Blogpost [InSight Update, sols 25-42: Seismometer sensors working! Tricky setup and cable management on Mars](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2019/insight-update-sols-25-42.html)

This is an animated **GIF:** It's fairly subtle, you may not notice at first!

[image]

IPGP / David Ducros

> VBB RECENTERING
>
> Animation showing the "recentering" operation of the InSight seismometer's Very Broad Band (VBB) seismic pendulums. Recentering is a calibration activity that fine-tunes the instrument's sensitivity to slow seismic waves. There are three VBB sensors in the SEIS instrument.

In some more technical detail, what is the effect of the recentering operation on the VBB seismic pendulums? Is it as simple as just making sure their equilibrium position is centered (which doesn't sound like a proper calibration) or is there more going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this paper](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2019/pdf/2256.pdf) the recentering operation seems to be adjusting the instrument's center of gravity (via the motor unit seen on the right of the animation). From the paper...

> To ensure the fine  equilibrium  of  the  highly  sensitive  pendulum,  a balancing mechanism (fig.1g) adjust the center of gravity  position

This is a translation from the original French, so the syntax is slightly odd.

[Here's](https://www.seis-insight.eu/en/public-2/seis-instrument/vbb-sensors) a more comprehensive discussion of the instrument, including an interactive PDF.

Comment: Okay I'm starting to understand. It sounds like it adjusting the equilibrium position, but not really "calibrating" from what I can read in these links so far. However, perhaps it does have a calibrating function as well.

Comment: Have a look at the inclined orientation in Fig. 2 in your [first link](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2019/pdf/2256.pdf), I think that it could serve as a basis for an answer to a question [How was InSight's vertical seismometer (accelerometer) tested in Earth's stronger gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32268/12102)